# How do I get the value of a fetch call to pass to my component and have the component re-render?

Tags: reactjs, components, fetch, rendering

I'm trying to build a React 16.13.0 application.  I have created the following FormContainer in which I'm trying to pass a value in a prop variable ("suggestions") after I load data in my "componentDidMount" method ...

```
class FormContainer extends Component {  
  static DEFAULT_COUNTRY = 484
  static REACT_APP_PROXY = process.env.REACT_APP_PROXY

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      countries: [],
      provinces: [],
      errors: [],
      newCoop: {
        name: '',
        types: [{
          name: ''
        }],
        address: {
          formatted: '',
          locality: {
            name: '',
            postal_code: '',
            state: ''
          },
          country: FormContainer.DEFAULT_COUNTRY,
        },
        enabled: true,
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        web_site: '' 
      },

    }

...

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="container-fluid" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
            <FormGroup
                controlId="formBasicText">      

                <Input inputType={'text'}
                   title= {'Name'} 
                   name= {'name'}
                   value={this.state.newCoop.name} 
                   placeholder = {'Enter cooperative name'}
                   handleChange = {this.handleInput}
                   errors = {this.state.errors} 
                   /> {/* Name of the cooperative */}
 
                <CoopTypes 
                  name={'types'}
                  suggestions = {this.state.coopTypes} 
                  values = {this.state.newCoop.types}
                  placeholder = {'Enter coop type(s)'}
                  handleAddition = {this.handleCoopTypeAddition}
                  handleDeletion = {this.handleCoopTypeDeletion}
                  errors = {this.state.errors}
                /> {/* Coop Type Selection */}

        ...
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let initialCountries = [];
    let initialProvinces = [];
    let coopTypes = [];
    ...
    // Get all possible coop types 
    fetch(FormContainer.REACT_APP_PROXY + '/coop_types/')
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
        coopTypes = data.map((coopType) => {
            return coopType
        });
        console.log("coop types:");
        console.log(coopTypes);
        this.setState({
            coopTypes: coopTypes,
        });
    });    
  }
}
```

Below is the component definition invoked in the form ...

```
class CoopTypes extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        console.log("sugestions:");
        console.log(props.suggestions); 
        const tags = props.values.map(result => (
            {
                id: result.id,
                text: result.name
            }));
        this.state = {
            tags: tags,
            suggestions: props.values.map(result => ({
                id: result.id,
                text: result.name
            }))
        };
        this.handleDelete = props.handleDelete;
        this.handleAddition = props.handleAddition;
        this.handleDrag = this.handleDrag.bind(this);
    }
 
    handleDelete(i) {
        const { tags } = this.state;
        this.setState({
         tags: tags.filter((tag, index) => index !== i),
        });
    }
 
    handleAddition(tag) {
        this.setState(state => ({ tags: [...state.tags, tag] }));
    }
 
    handleDrag(tag, currPos, newPos) {
        const tags = [...this.state.tags];
        const newTags = tags.slice();
 
        newTags.splice(currPos, 1);
        newTags.splice(newPos, 0, tag);
 
        // re-render
        this.setState({ tags: newTags });
    }
 
    render() {
        const { tags, suggestions } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <ReactTags tags={this.state.tags}
                    suggestions={this.state.suggestions}
                    handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
                    handleAddition={this.handleAddition}
                    handleDrag={this.handleDrag}
                    delimiters={delimiters} />
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default CoopTypes;
```

The problem is after the "fetch" call loads, the component doesn't re-render.  That is, it always renders with a value of "null" for the suggestions props.  What do I need to do so that after the fetch calls loads, the value is passed on to the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `suggestions: props.values.map(result`

1. wrong prop used,
2. updated props (if updated) are not reflected to state (constructor called once)

You can use `props.suggestions` (`.map`) directly in `render` (using local variables) without 'buffering' in state (and taking care of props updates). Using functional components can be easier to follow [dependencies].

**hint:**
You can place `console.log` in `render()` to be sure it is rendered (or not) with current suggestion props.

---

This looks a bit strange:

> ```
>     this.handleDelete = props.handleDelete;
>     this.handleAddition = props.handleAddition;
>     this.handleDrag = this.handleDrag.bind(this);
> ```

This looks a bit strange - your class handlers (`handleDelete`, 'handleAddition' functions) are your `this.handleDelete` and `this.handleAddition`. Overwriting them (in constructor) with props-handlers makes a little [no?] sense. Both this-handlers should be binded as `this.handleDrag` is. You can use props-handlers from this-handlers (conditionally, if defined).